# how to use special character in scala case class

Tags: scala, class, case

I am consuming the JSON below,

```
{
  "@context": "Testingcontext",
  "@type": "Testingtype",
  "actor": "Testingactor"
}
```

for which I am creating a case class in scala:

```
case class LoggedInAction(`@context`: String,`@type`:String,actor:String)
```

How can I use special character like `@`, `&` in a case class? Also, how to use such case class fields?

Comment: I don't get your problem. How to use special characters? You just did that in your code - using backticks. You access them with backticks as well, `LoggedInAction("c", "t", "asd").\`@context\``

Comment: I would set field mapping appropriately for your JSON framework and not pollute my case class with non-standard fields.

Comment: You should override the method formatter which parse json to scala instead try to use the same property name.. it depends of your json framework as manub said

Answer (score 5):

just to as you did in your example:

```
scala> case class LoggedInAction(`@context`: String,`@type`:String,actor:String)
defined class LoggedInAction

scala> val example = LoggedInAction("context", "type", "actor")
example: LoggedInAction = LoggedInAction(context,type,actor)

scala> example.`@context`
res0: String = context
```